# Using "SET /P" inside an IF statement

Tags: command-line, batch-file, cmd

I'm creating a batch to turn my laptop into wifi an make my life easier to type lines in cmd each time.

The trouble is the wifi name always get set to **key=** insted of the one which I enter.

Here is what I did:

```
@echo OFF
set /p option="Enter 1 to create wifi, Enter 2 to stop wifi "
IF %option% EQU 1 (
    set /p id="Enter wifi Name:"
    set /p key="Set password:"
    netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid = %id% key = %key%
    netsh wlan start hostednetwork
)

IF %option% EQU 2 (
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=disallow
)

timeout /t 5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got the solution

```
@echo off

echo What You What To Do ?
echo 1 to create wifi
echo 2 to stop wifi

set /p input=
if %input%==1 goto 1
if %input%==2 goto 2

:1
cls
set /p name=Enter wifi name 
set /p pass=Enter wifi password 
echo Creating wifi with
echo Name = %name% 
echo Password = %pass%
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid="%name%" key="%pass%"
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
timeout /t 5
exit;

:2
cls
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=disallow
exit;
timeout /t 5
```

Comment: +1, Your original problem has to do with when expansion occurs. You could have used your original code structure if you used delayed expansion. Delayed expansion is enabled using `setlocal enableDelayedExpansion`. For more info, type `help set` from a command prompt and start reading about half way down at the line that starts *"Finally, support for delayed environment variable expansion has been added..."*

Answer (score 14):

While you shouldn't have any spaces between the switch and the equal sign, or the equal sign and the parameter, the real culprit is because you're using `SET /P` inside the `IF` statement.

To correct this, you'll need to do two things:

1. Add `Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` to the top of your batch file, after the `@ECHO OFF` statement (so that the variables in the `IF` block can be expanded at execution time).
2. Since we're now using `EnableDelayedExpansion`, call all your variables using `!!` instead of `%%`, such as: 
   `netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=!id! key=!key!`

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood; I'm admittedly having a little difficulty reading your question.  What exactly is happenning?  Is the `ssid` being literally set to **key=**?

Comment: Yes ssid being set to **key=** , I want to set to which i enter

Comment: try to `echo %id%` after your `set` command. I'd bet, `%id%`is not defined.

Comment: @Stephan yes output is blank ( its not defined ), can you please help me. I'm new to batch

Comment: @BasicBridge - yeah, edited my answer.  I forgot that `SET /P` doesn't behave well inside an `IF` statement... it probably has to do with being evaluated at parse time versus execution time.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

SET /P myvar="Enter variables: "

set argCount=0
for %%x in (%myvar%) do (
   set /A argCount+=1
   set "argVec[!argCount!]=%%~x"
)

echo Number of processed arguments: %argCount%

for /L %%i in (1,1,%argCount%) do (
    echo %%i- "!argVec[%%i]!"
)
```

The result of calling the function will be:

```
function.bat
Enter variables: a b c
1- "a"
2- "b"
3- "c"
```

In this way, we can call the function with parameters, use the parameters in another part of the function, and iterate using new inputs from SET.

Comment: IMHO this answer is lacking some information on who and why your code is doing things. I wouldn't call an interactive set _parameters_, they are inputs.

Comment: For all people who have problems with this: The important thing is setlocal enabledelayedexpansion **AND** instead of calling %variable% try calling !variable!.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do it.  I also removed the spaces around ssid= and key= as that may be an issue.

```
@echo OFF
set "option="
set /p "option=Enter a name to create wifi, or just press Enter to stop wifi: "

IF not defined option (
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=disallow
goto :EOF
)

    set /p key="Set password:"
    netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=%option% key=%key%
    netsh wlan start hostednetwork

timeout /t 5
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what your trouble is, this simplified version of your code runs just fine for me:

```
@echo OFF
set /p option="Enter 1 to create wifi, Enter 2 to stop wifi "
IF %option% EQU 1 (
    echo Option 1
)

IF %option% EQU 2 (
    echo Option 2
)

timeout /t 5
```

This is my output -- the batch file was named 'z.bat'

```
C:\z>z
Enter 1 to create wifi, Enter 2 to stop wifi 1
Option 1

Waiting for 2 seconds, press a key to continue ...

C:\z>z
Enter 1 to create wifi, Enter 2 to stop wifi 2
Option 2

Waiting for 4 seconds, press a key to continue ...

C:\z>
C:\z>cmd /version
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for help @Jeremy J Starcher i got my trouble. SET /P will not work in if block. Any way i found the solution