# SET /p Inside an If Statement (Batch)

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, batch-file

I am writing a batch file to automate some trouble shooting steps.  To start, I want to identify whether or not the user has 'Protected Mode' enabled on their Internet Explorer browser.  If they do, I would like to prompt them to turn it off.  I am doing this through the system registry.

I am confident the registry key is correct because I have changed the value from 0 to 3 and it has behaved as I expect, toggling the 'Protected Mode' setting of the Internet zone in Internet Explorer.

Here is the current code:

```
@echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

REM Check protected mode
echo Checking Internet Explorer settings
set "regCmd=reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\3" /v 2500"
for /f "usebackq tokens=3* delims=   " %%a in (`!regCmd!`) do (
  set /a ProtectedMode=%%a
 )

if !ProtectedMode! == 0 (
    echo Protected mode in Internet Explorer is enabled.  It is recommended that protected mode be disabled in Internet Explorer.
    echo.
    set /P b_disable="Would you like to disable protected mode in Internet Explorer? (y/n)"
)
REM Checking to see that b_disable is set appropriately, it is
echo !b_disable!
REM Update protected mode to turn it off
if !b_disable!=="y" (
    echo Protected mode for Internet Explorer disabled.
)
if !b_disable!=="n" (
    echo Protected mode for Internet Explorer was NOT disabled.
)
pause
```

When I do have protected mode enabled, the output is currently:

> Checking Internet Explorer settings
>
> Protected mode in Internet Explorer is enabled.  It is recommended
>   that protected mode be disabled in Internet Explorer.
>
> Would you like to disable protected mode in Internet Explorer(y/n)y
>
> y
>
> Press any key to continue . . .

So the issue is that the if statement does not appear to be evaluated.  I need to know how to conditionally perform actions (I plan to implement code to update the registry value for the same key if the user presses y).

I learned about `SetLocal` and `EnableDelayedExpansion` as well as using `!variable!` to reference the set variables from [another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17601473/using-set-p-inside-an-if-statement)

This is my first batch file, and it is all very new to me.  Of course it would be way easier to simply tell the user to go into IE and uncheck 'Enable Protected Mode' but the task is to automate it, while allowing the user some control (hence the y/n prompts).

Comment: 1. I don't see the reason to use double quotes twice in set "regCmd=reg...  2. You can use a filter to get only the line with the registry ('!regCmd! ^| find "REG_DWORD"')    3. echo !ProtectedMode! before using it to check its value.

Comment: I used double quotes twice because the example I saw had double quotes in it, as I said this is the first batch file I've ever written.  I will attempt the filter as you suggest, that seems much cleaner.  I did echo !ProtectedMode! and the value is correct, it is coming back as a 3 or 0.

Comment: The find command seemed to just return all 3 values (key name, data type, and value).  This is what I was trying to avoid, as I only want the value (and hence the for loop that extracts only the value of 2500 from what was returned).  The command I tried was `reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\3" /v 2500 | find "REG_DWORD"`.  The result was the same.  Perhaps I am doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please be aware that the registry you want to check may not exist.
User input needs to be checked only if !ProtectedMode! == 0

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\3" /v 2500 2^>nul ^| find "REG_DWORD" 2^>nul') do (
    set /a ProtectedMode=%%a
)
echo ProtectedMode=!ProtectedMode!

if !ProtectedMode! == 0 (
    echo Protected mode in Internet Explorer is enabled.  It is recommended that protected mode be disabled in Internet Explorer.
    echo.
    set /P b_disable="Would you like to disable protected mode in Internet Explorer? (y/n): "
    REM Checking to see that b_disable is set appropriately, it is
    echo !b_disable!
    REM Update protected mode to turn it off
    if "!b_disable!"=="y" (
        echo Protected mode for Internet Explorer disabled.
    )
    if "!b_disable!"=="n" (
        echo Protected mode for Internet Explorer was NOT disabled.
    )
)
pause
```

Comment: That seems to do it, thanks for the help!  As someone new to batch files and really the command prompt in general, I don't know what `^>nul ^| find "REG_DWORD" 2^>nul')` means.  Is it just message suppression?  If you could kindly explain it, or perhaps point me to a good resource, I would be very grateful!  Thanks again.

Comment: >nul suppresses standard output. 2>nul suppresses error output stream. ^ is used to escape > character in the script. | is a pipe that streams the output of one command to input of another one. find "REG_DWORD" selects from the output just the lines containing REG_DWORD, otherwise we get several more lines.