# How to take input from command prompt using batch file

Tags: batch-file

I called the batch file from power shell
      `start-process "cmd.exe" "/c $createInDBs`"
I am trying to take input like name of the database from the command prompt using a batch file

Here is my code:

```
echo off
cd "C:\Program Files"
Choice /N /C ab /M "  <?> (A)Create All-in-one database   <?> (B)Create Individual database"
If Errorlevel 2 (
    set /p sIndiviName=Enter the name of webserver: 
    echo %sIndiviName% is an Individual Database.
) Else (
set /p sAllName=Enter the name of  All-in-one database:
echo %sAllName% is an All-in-one Database.
pause
)
```

cmd.exe is asking for the name of the database, but in the command, the database is not taken

I got 'is an All-in-one Database'
Name of the database is not displayed

Comment: See [Using “SET /P” inside an IF statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17601473/using-set-p-inside-an-if-statement).

Comment: You are not using `delayedexpansion` you are setting and using variables inside code blocks, so you the correct way is to `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and replace your variable `%`s with `!`s For instance: `echo !sAllName!`